# New to HTML having issues altering font size with Big Cartel's Sidecar Theme

Tags: css, fonts, bigcartel

I'm new to code and sort of stumbling around at this point - Please bear with me.

I found a query in this forum for someone trying to edit font type, and tried their fix, but it didn't help with my specific issue.

I didn't know that I should only do edits at the end until recently, so I've already done quite a bit in the stylesheet(hope that's what it's called). I've already edited the font sizes for my sidebar menus and titles, but I can't seem to find a way to fix the rest. The font that needs fixing is the body of all pages, FAQS, about section, product descriptions, etc.

I'd like to keep it responsive to all devices, but really on my phone it doesn't seem near as tiny as it does on a regular computer screen. I haven't tested it on a tablet, but I'm assuming it's tiny there, too.

Should I go back and change all my previous work to continue? I hate to do things incorrectly, but I've done so much work that I'd hate to undo.
Here's my mess. [Silver Frame Soap Works](http://www.silverframesoapworks.com)

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry if you think i didn't got your point but as far as i got your problem. The solution is you should give the font family in the body element in your main style sheet and make it **!important** if it is not applied.

As

```
body{
font-family: arial !important;
}
```

it'll overwrite the other font-family already given. And if the font you are applying is not in the list of commonly available font families then import it by pasting link from google fonts in your css file. This will help you to import the font : https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started